# Java - finding the winner between 4 players using getter (War card game)

Tags: java, class, methods

Hi there I am trying to get this to calculate the winner from 4 players (The game is the classic card game war) but I can only get it to do two. the first bit of the code is my Card class and the second bit is the main program where there are more if statements for working out the winner. the issue i'm having is with the method "getWinner". I have included the deck class also if that is needed (at the bottom).
    package warcard;

```
public class Card
{
   private int value, suit;
   private String result, suitStr;

   /**
    * @param num represents value of card
    * @param type represents the suit of card
    */

   public Card(int num, int type)
   {
     /** 
      * Class constructor.
      */

      value = num;
      suit = type;

      switch(value)
      {
         case 1: result = "Ace";
                  break;
         case 2: result = "Two";
                 break;
         case 3: result = "Three";
                 break;
         case 4: result = "Four";
                 break;
         case 5: result = "Five";
                 break;
         case 6: result = "Six";
                 break;
         case 7: result = "Seven";
                 break;
         case 8: result = "Eight";
                 break;
         case 9: result = "Nine";
                 break;
         case 10: result = "Ten";
                 break;
         case 11: result = "Jack";
                 break;
         case 12: result = "Queen";
                 break;
         case 13: result = "King";
                 break;
         default: result = "";
                 break;
      }  


      switch(suit)
      {
         case 1: suitStr = "Clubs";
                 break;
         case 2: suitStr = "Diamonds";
                 break;
         case 3: suitStr = "Hearts";
                 break;
         case 4: suitStr = "Spades";
                 break;
      }

   }


    /**
    * getters
    */

   public int getNum()
   {
      return value;
   }



public int getSuit()
   {
      return suit;
   }

   /**
    * setters
    */

   public void setVal(int choice)
   {
      value = choice;
   }

   public void setSuit(int choice)
   {
      suit = choice;
   }

   /**
    * @param play represents Cards object
    * @return flag the String result of the game
    */ 

   public String getWinner(Card play)
   {
      String flag = "";

      if(value == play.getNum())
      {
         if(suit > play.getSuit())
            flag = "win";
         else if (suit == play.getSuit())
            flag = "tie";
         else
            flag = "lose";
      } 
      else if (value > play.getNum())
         flag = "win";
      else
         flag = "lose";

      return flag;

   }


   /** 
    * toString method
    */

   public String toString()
   {
     String info = "";
     info = info + result +  " of " + suitStr;
     return info;
   }

} /** end Cards class */
```

main program

```
package warcard;

public class Warcard
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // instantiation of 2 decks 
      Deck hand1, hand2, hand3, hand4;
      hand1 = new Deck();
      hand2 = new Deck();
      hand3 = new Deck();
      hand4 = new Deck();

      String result = "";

      // shuffle the decks 
      hand1.shuffle();
      hand2.shuffle();
      hand3.shuffle();
      hand4.shuffle();


      /** tracker variables
       *  wins1 tracks user's wins
       *  wins2 tracks computer's wins
       */
      int count = 0;
      int wins1 = 0;
      int wins2 = 0;
      int wins3 = 0;
      int wins4 = 0;
      int ties = 0; 


         for (int i= 0; i < 52; i++)
          { 


             Card tester = hand1.getCard(count);
             Card tester2 = hand2.getCard(count);
             Card tester3 = hand3.getCard(count);
             Card tester4 = hand4.getCard(count);
             count++;
             System.out.println("Player 1's hand: " + tester);
             System.out.println("Player 2's hand: " + tester2);
             System.out.println("Player 3's hand: " + tester3);
             System.out.println("Player 4's hand: " + tester4);
             result = tester.getWinner(tester2);


             if(result == "win")
             {
               System.out.println("Win!");
               wins1++;
             }
             else if(result == "tie")
             { 
               System.out.println("Tie!");
               ties++;
             }
             else
             {
               System.out.println("Lose!");
               wins2++;
             }

            } // end for loop

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Total score:");
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Player 1's wins: " + wins1 + "\n" + "Player 2's wins: " + wins2 + "\n" + "Player 3's wins: " + wins3 + "\n" + "Player 4's wins: " + wins4 + "\n" + "Ties: " + ties);
       if (wins1 > wins2 && wins1 > wins3 && wins1 > wins4)
          System.out.println("Player 1 won the game!");
       else if(wins2 > wins1 && wins2 > wins3 && wins2 > wins4)
           System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
       else if(wins3 > wins1 && wins3 > wins2 && wins3 > wins4)
           System.out.println("Player 3 wins!");
       else if(wins4 > wins1 && wins4 > wins2 && wins4 > wins3)
           System.out.println("Player 4 wins!");
       else if(wins1 == wins2 && wins1 == wins3 && wins1 == wins4)
          System.out.println("It's a tie!");


   }  // end main

} // end class
```

Deck class

```
package warcard;

import java.util.Random;

public class Deck
{
   private Card[] deck;
   private int[] suit = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   private int[] numbers = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
   private int count;

   public Deck()
   {
     deck = new Card[52];
     count = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
      {
         for(int k = 2; k <= 14; k++)
            {
              deck[count] = new Card(k, suit[i]);
               count++;
              }
       } /** 
          * end outer loop 
          */

   } 
   /**
    * end constructor 
    */



   public Card getCard(int index)
   {

     return deck[index];
   }




   public void shuffle() 
   {
      int rand;
      Random mix = new Random();

         for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
         {
            /** 
             * shuffles deck
             */

            rand = mix.nextInt(deck.length);
            Card temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[rand];
            deck[rand] = temp;

         } /**
            * end for loop
            */

   }



} /**  end DeckCards class */
```

Comment: Whats ur problem exactly? Are you taking exceptions, or your code produces incorrect answer?

Comment: @Everv0id The issue is that it is not picking up that player 3 and 4 are playing as can be seen by this (this is when i run the program)             Player 1's wins: 24
Player 2's wins: 26
Player 3's wins: 0
Player 4's wins: 0
Ties: 2
Player 2 wins!

Comment: Add 3 more `Card` parameters to `getWinner` and adjust that method to compare against all 3 cards instead of just 1. Right now, you are only passing in 1 card, meaning p1's card is only being compared to p2's card. You're gonna want to do `tester.getWinner(tester2, tester3, tester4)`, then adjust that method to work with the new parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are only comparing the values of 2 cards; you're comparing `tester` against `tester2`, but do not include player 3 or player 4's cards. Not only that, you don't return *which* player has won. Instead, you only specify whether p1 has won or lost.

Your  `String getWinner(Card)` method needs more parameters, so you can pass more cards into it. Compare against all the cards. It should also return *which* player has won:

```
public String getWinner(Card p2, Card p3, Card p4) {
    //compare against ALL cards
    //return which player won
}
```

You would then call this, passing in all opposing cards, not just `tester2`:

```
result = tester.getWinner(tester2, tester3, tester4);
```

Finally, you have to fix up your score keeper. Instead of checking for "win" or "lose", check for which player won:

```
/* could use a switch statement */
if(result == "p1") {
           System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
           wins1++;
} else if(result == "p2") { 
           System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
           wins2++;
} else if(result == "p3") {
           //...
}
```

If I were on a computer, I'd suggest a LOT more, such as encapsulating the "battle" somewhere else rather than within the first player's Card; I recommend posting to CodeReview once you are done. If you have any problems, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, only the tester-deck is playing against the tester2-deck. If thats not intended, the reason, only 2 of your 4 decks are "competitive" ist that only 2 of them do play, right?

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I actually wanted this to be a comment but turns out you need 50 reputation to comment, which i currently dont have.

Comment: Well yes that is my issue but i dont know how to resolve it. its comparing player 1 and 2 but i dont know how to get it to compare 3 and 4 also!

Comment: Actually, you cold do it exactly the same way you did with 0 and 2, but Id recommend you to make wins a public variable of the class deck and then write something like                                                                              fight(Deck a, Deck b);                                                                                      this method could then add  a point to a.wins or b.wins depending on who won.